# listview does not display update item with ajax in asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview

i use listview and ajax in asp.net web form ... in part of form, display comments and readers can positive score or negative score but while user click on positive or negative button, update value is not display unless page is refresh.
please help me

```
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="row comm_info_bar ">
                                <div class="col-md-5 RightDisplay"><%# Eval("name") %></div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 comm_info_date"><%# Eval("date") %></div>

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="negBtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus voteCommentIcon voteContNeg text-danger smallGlyph" runat="server" CommandName="negative" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' />

                                <asp:Label ID="lblnegative" name="lblnegative" class=" voteNumNeg" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "negative") %>'></asp:Label>

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="posBtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus voteCommentIcon voteContNeg text-success smallGlyph" runat="server" CommandName="positive" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblpositive" class="voteNumPos" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "positive") %>'></asp:Label>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 comments"><%# Eval("text") %></div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you post code which is more understandable. Where is your ajax part ?

Comment: Please add a minimum executable example (see [ask]). Furthermore please explain more thoroughly what you are trying to achieve and *how*. And which steps you have taken to solve your issue.